# How to get into POSXML development

Tags: ide, point-of-sale, pos

How does someone go about getting into application development for point of sale (POS) systems.

Is there a specific IDE used for it? How does one go about compiling/testing their application?

Comment: Your question is too broad and unlikely to give you the right answer. It is no different from a normal computer application, except that it uses peripherals that are specific to some point-of-sale terminals. Vendors often provide SDKs linked to the POS terminal or peripheral device you are going to use, but there seems to be a choice among them, so please choose the one that you think is good. You can use what you want to use according to the requirements and desires of you or your customers. You should narrow down the usage environment and requirements before asking a question.

Comment: By the way, if it's about the word `POSXML`, it might be this site. [Introduction](https://docs.cloudwalk.io/en/introduction), [POSXML - Language structure](https://docs.cloudwalk.io/en/posxml/structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with the [Point-of-Service docs and samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/point-of-service) from the Microsoft online documentation for developers.